# How to create a copy of DVD that is larger than maximum size of file on filesystem?

Tags: dvd

How to create copy of DVD, which ISO image size is larger than maximum size of file on filesystem?  There is only one DVD drive.

Comment: What UNIX/Linux filesystem are you using that has such a small maximum file size?

Comment: VFAT (FAT32) in quite old kernel has limit of 4GB file size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't mind that the intermediate storage won't be usable as such:

```
split -b 1024m /dev/dvd iso-pieces.
# Pop out original, pop in blank
cat iso-pieces.* | growisofs -Z /dev/dvd=/dev/stdin
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will probably use `dd` or `cdread` instead of `split`-ting on device, though.

Comment: @Jakub: `dd` is useless here, it won't do anything for you that `cat` wouldn't do. But see [Calculate md5sum of a CD/DVD](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/calculate-md5sum-of-a-cd-dvd) about reading a CD's filesystem image exactly.

Comment: I meant using e.g. `dd if=/dev/dvd of=iso-piece.2 bs=1024m count=1 skip=1024m` etc. instead of `split`.